# exclude one page from https

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 pages in my site that one hold form and other does call to API that doesn't support in https for now.

I want to have the page with the form in https and the second one in HTTP.

I wrote this code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/generator2.php/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://lotterymoneyapp.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/generator2.php/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://lotterymoneyapp.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and it doesn't do the trick. 
I also want that if someone enters to generator2.php file with https it will send him to the HTTP because otherwise, nothing is working in the page (API isn't working).

what can I do next?

p.s
the homepage with the form send the user to the generator2 page after signup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `REQUEST_URI` may change due to execution of other rules.

Keep these rules at the top before other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/generator\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://lotterymoneyapp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /generator\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://lotterymoneyapp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# rest of your rules go below this
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing or use a new browser.